# Navigation breaks with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap for a basic web site I'm working on.

Here is my Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/sk6g3ykp/1/

To best see my issue, here's the full page: https://jsfiddle.net/sk6g3ykp/1/embedded/result/. My problem is - if you resize that full page down until you see the hamburger icon and then resize it back to desktop size - see how the phone number is no longer aligned. **Why is this?**

Here's my **CSS**:

```
.navbar-default {
    border-color: transparent;
    background-color: #222;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand {
    font-family: "Kaushan Script","Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,cursive;
    color: #1b7ae0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-brand:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:focus,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand:active,
.navbar-default .navbar-brand.active {
    color: #1b7ae0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-collapse {
    border-color: rgba(255,255,255,.02);
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #1b7ae0;
    background-color: #1b7ae0;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #1b7ae0;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-family: Montserrat,"Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    color: #fff;
}

.navbar-default .nav li a:hover,
.navbar-default .nav li a:focus {
    outline: 0;
    color: #1b7ae0;
}

/*.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b7ae0;
}*/

.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #1b7ae0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-default {
        padding: 25px 0;
        border: 0;
        background-color: transparent;
        -webkit-transition: padding .3s;
        -moz-transition: padding .3s;
        transition: padding .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 2em;
        -webkit-transition: all .3s;
        -moz-transition: all .3s;
        transition: all .3s;
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a {
        border-radius: 3px;
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink {
        padding: 10px 0;
        background-color: #222;
    }

    .navbar-default.navbar-shrink .navbar-brand {
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }
}


    .navbar-inverse {
        background:transparent;
        border:0;
    }

    .navbar-default .nav li a {
        text-transform:none;
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 1.1em;
    }

    .nav>li>a {
        padding:10px 20px;
    }

    .navbar-default{
      text-align:center;
      margin-top:30px;
    }
    .navbar-center{
       display: inline-block;
       float: none; 
    }

        .navbar-center p {
            font-weight: 300;
            font-size: 1.1em;
            color:#fff;
            padding:10px 20px
        }

    @media(max-width:768px) {
        .navbar-default {
            margin-top:0px!important;
        }
        .navbar-center {
            display:none    
        }
    }

    .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover {
        background:transparent;
        color:#fff;
    }


.navbar-brand {
    width:265px;
    height:37px;
    background: url('/wp-content/themes/gf/assets/img/logo.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}

@media(max-width:480px) {
.navbar-brand {
    width:74px;
    height:37px;
    background: url('/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/logo2.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
}

nav {
    background:red!important
}
```

Many thanks for any guidance.

Comment: It is not happening in my chrome. Can I know which browser are you using?

Comment: Yes, I'm also using Chrome. The most recent version. Have you tried resizing it from full width down to mobile and back up? The phone number goes 'above' the navigation.

Comment: I tried it. I'm using Chrome Version 41.0.2272.89 (64-bit) + Mac os x yosemite

Comment: This is what i get; http://imgur.com/Vzleito

Comment: Yes. I'm getting this in medium size screen. Let me check.

Comment: I want to stop this from happening :-) Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have added some extra css to make the text center aligned. It is breaking due to the relative position.

Following code will solve that.

```
.navbar-center{
     display: inline-block;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -140px;
}
```

Updated jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/sk6g3ykp/4/